# Laravel function static function calling

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I am new to laravel and i cannot understand the following code while learning laravel
i know that we use '::' to call the static function of a class but using '->' after calling the static function creates confusion for me

```
use App\Post;
 Route::get('/forcedelete', function () {
     Post::withTrashed()->where('id',1)->forcedelete();
 });;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is a chained call. The following code would have the same result:

```
$query = Post::withTrashed();
$query = $query->where('id', 1);
$query->forceDelete();
```

The first line returns a `Builder|Model` instance ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with)), so when you want to use it (second line), you're not in a static context anymore so you have to use the arrow.